# Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).querySelectorAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console

I am a pretty big project, it is made with `angular` , `node` , `express`.
When I start my application I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError . This.get ( ... ) is not a function querySelectorAll

But the application continues running without any problem apparently .

I do not know what could be causing this error because as you can see in the screenshot , the error takes about VW838 files called and other `angular`.

I do not know when this error appeared.

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

This is the error screenshot:

[image: this.get(...).querySelectorAll is not a function]

**SOLUTION**

I've solved it uninstalling and installing chrome again.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint using Google Chromes developer tools at the beginning when you first register your module and then seeing where it breaks?

Comment: Yes, I had no success. Because the error appears in a file called VW838 , I do not know where the project is located

Comment: please post some relevant code

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest. Maybe try removing scripts until it stops erroring. Without knowing exactly where the problem is, it's best to simplyify the project.

Comment: I launched the apllicación of private browsing. The error does not appear.

Comment: likely the problem is a chrome extension with broken code

Comment: I also met this error when running **`elem.textContent = str;`**, only occured in a few people's computer. It seems that it is a browser bug.

Answer (score 1):

Very likely it's caused by some chrome extension.

You can disable chrome extensions one by one and reload your page to see whether the error exists.

Search for `.get(0).querySelectorAll` in the Chrome extensions folder and all subfolders. Most likely it's `.get(0)` based on the direct use of `querySelectorAll` afterwards.

See [this disscussion](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2738)